# Does Netflix Feign support xml configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-feign

Is it possible to configure Feign Client in other way, instead of annotations ? I am asking this, because I am trying to separate my business logic and infrastructure in to different layers.

Comment: And why would XML help with that? It still is configuration, you can split those up as well...

Comment: You are right, this is still configuration, but xml provides me flexibility to change for example request mapping path without re-compile all project.

Comment: Well it saves you the compile but you still need to repackage your application... So actually you don't gain anything... Also you can put that stuff in property files and have it applied at startup.